# Qt - Is there a way to check if the window is marked always-on-top (linux)?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to check if the Qt window is marked always-on-top (by the user)? I would like to check that on closeEvent() and save it for the next time the user opens the window.

P.S: I checked the `windowFlags` hoping that `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag will be set, but the flags don't seem to be affected.

Comment: When you change the ```Qt::WindowStayOnTopHint```, the file manager can see the change but I can't think that Qt detect change flags from file manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xlib`, the needed *window state* hint can be checked calling the `XGetWindowProperty` function.

Check requisites first, e.g. `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`.

In the `pro` file, link `xlib` and require the `x11extras` qt module.

```
QT += x11extras
LIBS += -lX11
```

This is a working example, a function that returns `true` if the passed-in widget pointer points to a *always-on-top* window:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <QtX11Extras/QX11Info>

bool isAlwaysOnTop(QWidget * widget)
{
    Atom atr;
    int  afr;
    unsigned long items;
    unsigned long bytes;
    unsigned char *data;

    Display * display = QX11Info::display();
    Atom property = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
    if(XGetWindowProperty(display, widget->winId(), property, 0L, 1L, False, 4, &atr, &afr, &items, &bytes, &data) == 0)
    {
        Atom abv = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE", False);
        Atom res = reinterpret_cast<Atom *>(data)[0];
        return (res==abv);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It can be used from inside the widget `closeEvent`:

```
void Form::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
{
    qDebug() << isAlwaysOnTop(this);
}
```